# How to search prior questions?

Tags: discussion

There has to be search function for this forum.

I am sure this has been asked many times.

How do I change the screen size?

Ralph

Comment: If you're using mobile site, there's magnifying glass icon  below "Questions" link. On desktop site, the search bar is right on the main page. Otherwise, use a search engine and include "askubuntu.com" into the query

Comment: is this actually a meta question? It looks like a main question with a misleading title...

Comment: @Zanna I think those are two questions, one for each. Answering the meta question seems like teaching OP and others how to fish.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I don't like the Stack Exchange search. I use google instead, with `site:askubuntu.com` to search here specifically, like `change screen size site:askubuntu.com`.

Though often there's helpful info on other sites like Super User, Unix & Linux, How-to Geek, Ubuntu Forums, etc, so I just put `ubuntu` in the query, like `ubuntu change screen size`.